# How to add check box using field-wrap tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add check using field-wrap tag, but space submit button and check box non-aligned. I have to two forms called sign up and login. Sign up form contains many fields like name, email, password, etc.. Tried in terms and condition using checkbox in sign up form, but alignment is messed up.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4F5459;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #71D72C;
}

.form .forgot p {

  color: #4F5459;

}

.form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3); */
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  height: 50%;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #4F5459;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #4F5459;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 14px;
  color: #4F5459;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: #4F5459;
}

label.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(35px);
          transform: translateY(35px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #4F5459;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #E7E8E6;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #4F5459;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #71D72C;
}



textarea {
  border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #71D72C;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <!-- <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1> -->
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Business Name<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          <h1 style="font-size:14px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600">Payment</h1>

          <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                  Name on Card<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Card Number<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="number"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
          <div class="top-row">

              <h1 style="font-size:14px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600">Expiration</h1>

          <div class="field-wrap">

            <label>
             MM<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>


            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                 YYYY<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
               CVC<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label><input type="checkbox" />Option 1</label>

              <!-- <input type="checkbox" required autocomplete="off" /> -->
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" required autocomplete="off"> -->
             <!-- <label class="req form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label> -->
             </div>


          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Sign Up</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
          <!-- <h1>Welcome Back!</h1> -->
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

From snippet can able to see check box and submit button are non aligned. How to add check box like above input field with correct space?

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from `label`

Comment: thanks for answering... now space looks good but check box and text are messing up each other and check box is not clickable @AnureshVP

Comment: I can't see the checkbox

Comment: @AnureshVP check box is mingle with sign up button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have coded CSS for input, so for all input element, it will take `width:100%` & `height:100%` etc...

See the attached snippet

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4F5459;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #71D72C;
}

.form .forgot p {

  color: #4F5459;

}

.form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3); */
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  height: 50%;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #4F5459;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #4F5459;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

label {
/*  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
   transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 14px;
  pointer-events: none;*/
  color: #4F5459;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: #4F5459;
}

label.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(35px);
          transform: translateY(35px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #4F5459;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #E7E8E6;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #4F5459;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #71D72C;
}
[type=checkbox], [type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


textarea {
  border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #71D72C;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #71D72C;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form">
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup"> 
      <!-- <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1> -->
      
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label> First Name<span class="req">*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label> Last Name<span class="req">*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Email Address<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="email" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Password<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Business Name<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <h1 style="font-size:14px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600">Payment</h1>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Name on Card<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Card Number<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="number" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="top-row">
          <h1 style="font-size:14px; text-align: left; font-weight: 600">Expiration</h1>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label> MM<span class="req">*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label> YYYY<span class="req">*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> CVC<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" >
            Option 1</label>
          
          <!-- <input type="checkbox" required autocomplete="off" /> --> 
          <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" required autocomplete="off"> --> 
          <!-- <label class="req form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label> --> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="login"> 
      <!-- <h1>Welcome Back!</h1> -->
      
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Email Address<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="email" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label> Password<span class="req">*</span> </label>
          <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
        <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- tab-content --> 
  
</div>
<!-- /form -->
```